# How can I deactivate images with an onClick Event using JavaScript ? (Working on browser extension)

Tags: javascript, image, browser, onclick

popup.html looks like this:

```
<div id="no-img" onClick="noImg()">
    <p> Disable images </p>
</div>
```

background.js (Thats how I tried but it doesn't work) :

```
function noImg () {
var disable = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i < eles.length; i++)
disable[i].onclick = null;
}
```

How can I make all the images on a page disabled by clicking on the paragraph tag and enabled by clicking again?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the previous value to another attribute to swap it back later, for example

```
function noImg () {
  var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
      swap;

  for (var i=0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    swap = elems[i].onclick;
    elems[i].onclick = elems[i].saveclick;
    elems[i].saveclick = swap;
  }
}
```